# Native Facebook authentication in .net maui or xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I'm looking for working example of application that implements native  facebook authentication.
I saw couple examples (also this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?tabs=android) but it can open and manage only browser page and force client to login with password and etc. I want to have better experiance and open facebook app if is installed. Is there any example or library that is supported and working?

Comment: I'm in the same dilemma

Comment: I found these links for native authentication with xamarin forms, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/native-android-facebook-authentication-azure-app-service/ https://evgenyzborovsky.com/2018/03/09/using-native-facebook-login-button-in-xamarin-forms/